# Django removing duplicated images

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return random but distinct images from a given directory.

I have written a function that will return a random image from a directory but I need it to return distinct images, at the moment it returns images but some of them are duplicated.

What is the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

---

**random_image.py**

```
def random_image(image_dir):
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif']
    rand_dir = '/static/app_pickfeel/images/'
    # print(rand_dir)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + '/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images')
             if f[f.rfind("."):len(f)] in valid_extensions]
    print(random.choice(files))

    return rand_dir + random.choice(files)
```

I'm using the function in **template.html** calling this multiple times

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image 'app_pickfeel/images/' %}">
```

Comment: I assume you are calling this in a loop?

Comment: I have edited my initial question to clarify my point. I am not currently running this in a loop just calling it multiple times in a template.

Comment: That's basically running it in a loop. You will need to keep state, and the best way to do it here is to generate the random image list in your view function, then pass it to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want `random.sample()`, which returns `n` random unique options from a list, instead of calling this function in a loop.

```
import os

valid_extensions = {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'}
rand_path = '/static/app_pickfeel/images'
rand_dir = settings.BASE_DIR + '/app_pickfeel/' + rand_path

def random_images(n):
    files = [
        f 
        for f 
        in os.listdir(rand_dir)
        if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] in valid_extensions
    ]
    return [
        os.path.join(rand_dir, f)
        for f
        in random.sample(files, n)
    ]
```

Then, invoking

```
images = random_images(5)
```

would get you a list of (up to) 5 random filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to remove duplicates from the list

```
def random_image(image_dir):
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif']
    rand_dir = '/static/app_pickfeel/images/'
    # print(rand_dir)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + '/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images')
             if f[f.rfind("."):len(f)] in valid_extensions]
    remove_duplicate = set(files)
    final_list = list(remove_duplicate)
    print(random.choice(final_list))

    return rand_dir + random.choice(final_list)
```

Hopes this helps you...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented what you suggested but it still outputs duplicates.

Comment: The duplicates aren't in `files` (file names are unique within a directory) - the op is, obviously, calling this function in a loop.